# JSF NullPointerException on Retrieving UIComponent ID?

Tags: java, jsf, exception, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

**UPDATE:

Adding CommandButton Code at the end of HTML file.**

Html code is simply like:

```
<div class="wrapperlist pad1">
                <h:dataTable id='table' value='#{reservation.flightList}' var='item' class="imagetable">                    
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header" class="imagetable th">
                        <h:outputText value="From" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.fromPlace}" />
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header" class="imagetable th">
                        <h:outputText value="TO" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.toPlace}" />
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header" class="imagetable th">
                        <h:outputText value="Outbound Date" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.outbound}" />
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header" class="imagetable th">
                        <h:outputText value="Returned" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.returned}" />
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header" class="imagetable th">
                        <h:outputText value="Availiable Seats" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText id="seatsNum" value="#{item.seats}" />
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header" class="imagetable th">
                        <h:outputText value="Flight Class" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.tripClass}" />
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header" class="imagetable th">
                        <h:outputText value="Airlines" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.airline}" />
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header" class="imagetable th">
                        <h:outputText value="Flight Type" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.tripType}" />
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header" class="imagetable th">
                        <h:outputText value="Price/Adult" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.priceForAdult}" />
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header" class="imagetable th">
                        <h:outputText value="Price/Child" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.priceForChild}" />
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header" class="imagetable th">
                        <h:outputText value="Total Adults Payment" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.priceForAdult * reservation.adults}" />
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header" class="imagetable th">
                        <h:outputText value="Total Childs Payment" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.priceForChild * reservation.children}" />
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header" class="imagetable th">
                        <h:outputText value="Total Payment" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{(item.priceForChild * reservation.children) + (item.priceForAdult * reservation.adults)}" />
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header" class="imagetable th">
                        <h:outputText value="Select" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="selected" ></h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
            </div>
            <h:form>
            <h:commandButton value="Confirm" action="#{flights.processOrder()}" class="button1     left relative"></h:commandButton> 
           </h:form>
```

It's a typical datatable, and its work fine.
My backing bean code is:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class Flights {

public Flights() {
    System.out.println("intialization");
}

public void processOrder()
{        
    UIViewRoot viewRoot = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();
    UIComponent component = viewRoot.findComponent("table:1:selected");
    System.out.println("component.getValueExpression(); " + component.getId());

}   
}
```

I get an exception when trying to print **component.getId()**, I tried **SessionScoped** but still having the same exception.
My goal is to access the ***checkboxes*** in the **datatable** to retrieve their values.

Comment: what is number on in your code viewRoot.findComponent("table:1:selected"); ?! .. and the cause of null pointer is that it couldn't find this component of id 'table:1:selected' .. i recommend you to use binding attribute to get selected value.

Comment: the path to your element may need to be :table:1:selected, you may need the colon before table.